# Kotlin data class and 30+ attributes

Tags: kotlin, data-class

how do we create data classes in kotlin , where the class contains more than 25+ attributes.

Use case is there is a class in java which has more than 25+ attributes and is needed to be converted to kotlin data class, morever the question would be is it appropriate to do so and if so how can we do that?

Comment: yeah, you can use data classes. And you do it just like you'd create any data class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Here an example:

```
data class Data(
    val a00: Int,
    val a01: Int,
    val a02: Int,
    val a03: Int,
    val a04: Int,
    val a05: Int,
    val a06: Int,
    val a07: Int,
    val a08: Int,
    val a09: Int,
    val a10: Int,
    val a11: Int,
    val a12: Int,
    val a13: Int,
    val a14: Int,
    val a15: Int,
    val a16: Int,
    val a17: Int,
    val a18: Int,
    val a19: Int,
    val a20: Int,
    val a21: Int,
    val a22: Int,
    val a23: Int,
    val a24: Int,
    val a25: Int,
    val a26: Int,
    val a27: Int,
    val a28: Int,
    val a29: Int,
    val a30: Int,
    val a31: Int,
    val a32: Int,
    val a33: Int,
    val a34: Int,
    val a35: Int,
    val a36: Int,
    val a37: Int,
    val a38: Int,
    val a39: Int,
    val a40: Int,
    val a41: Int,
    val a42: Int,
    val a43: Int,
    val a44: Int,
    val a45: Int,
    val a46: Int,
    val a47: Int,
    val a48: Int,
    val a49: Int
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val d = Data(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
        10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
        20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,
        30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,
        40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49)

    val copy = d.copy(a42 = 99)
}
```